# Setting the min_scaling_capacity parameter to 0 in an ECS cluster with EC2 deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy an ECS cluster with EC2 deployment using CDK. I am using the QueueProcessingEc2Service ECS pattern.

Here is the stack

```
from aws_cdk import core, aws_ecs_patterns, aws_ec2, aws_ecs


class EcsTestStack(core.Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    _container_image = aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(
        directory=".",
        file='Dockerfile.ECS_Test',
        exclude=["cdk.out"]
    )

    vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(self, "ecs-test-vpc-v4", max_azs=3)

    cluster = aws_ecs.Cluster(self, "ecs-test-cluster-v4", vpc=vpc)

    cluster.add_capacity("ecs-autoscaling-capacity-v4",
                         instance_type=aws_ec2.InstanceType("t2.small"),
                         min_capacity=0,
                         max_capacity=3)

    self.ecs_test = aws_ecs_patterns.QueueProcessingEc2Service(
        self,
        "ECS_Test_Pattern_v4",
        cluster=cluster,
        cpu=512,
        memory_limit_mib=512,
        image=_container_image,
        min_scaling_capacity=0,
        max_scaling_capacity=5,

    )
```

I would like to stack to be 'cold' when the queue is empty and spin up an EC2 instance and the ECS service and task only when messages get added to the queue.

Setting the `min_scaling_capacity` to 0 on the `QueueProcessingEc2Service` and `cluster.add_capacity` makes the stack not deploy. i,e. the deployment freezes at step 48/56(attaching screenshot). I've deleted the stack from CloudFormation and redeployed and get the same result.  When I add the -v flag to the CDK deploy command I get a bunch of `Stack EcsTestStackV4 has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (CREATE_IN_PROGRESS)` and nothing else. (attaching screenshot)
[image]

It seems to deploy fine when I have the `min_scaling_capacity` set to 1.

Question: Is setting the min_scaling_capacity to 0 valid? and if it is, why doesn't my stack deeply when it is set to 0?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you are experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum size for `min_scaling_capacity` is `1`. So even if you set to it  `0`, it will be set to `1`.

I guess it didn't work when you set `min_capacity=0`. In this case there are **no instances** in your cluster and no task will be able to deploy. `QueueProcessingEc2Service` does not scale out your instances, so you end up with empty auto scaling group.

`QueueProcessingEc2Service` is only about scaling your tasks, not the instances on which these task run.